# How do I join dataframes in python where each dataframe has a column which represents different processes values at a specific time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

My title is a bit messy but hopefully the information below is specific enough.

I have a script that scrapes the name and price of items from a online store and stores them in a pandas dataframe with 2 columns, Name and Price. The script runs at regular time periods and exports the data to a csv.
Now I want to combine the data to analyze the trends of different product prices over time. The issue I have is that the items scraped on any day are not necessarily the same as other days and the order of the items also differ.
How would I be able to store the price data in a dataframe where each row represents a specific product.

EDIT:
My inputs would be a few tables like this where each table is from a specific date and items might differ and the order might differ as well

| Item | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Car | 100 |
| Bike | 200 |
| ... | ... |

Output that i desire:

| Item | yesterday | today | tomorrow | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car | 100 | 200 | 150 | NA |
| House | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | ... |
| Bike | NA | 10 | 10 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: @PieCot I have edited and tried to provide examples

Comment: it's a merge, renaming columns.... `df.merge(df2, on="Item", how="outer", suffixes=("_today", "_yesterday")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can partition the data and generate a pivot table to produce your desired outcome.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Item": ["Car", "Bike", "Car", "Bike", "Car", "Bike",],
        "Price": ["100", "", "200", "10", "150", "10"],
        })

# Use pd.concat() to join multiple dataframes.
# e.g. - pd.concat([df1, df2])
# Then move onto the next part of this solution

df["partition"] = df.groupby("Item").cumcount()

result = df.pivot(index="Item", columns="partition", values="Price")

print(result)
```

Output -

```
partition    0    1    2
Item                    
Bike             10   10
Car        100  200  150
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a 'concat' function in pandas:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

First: I initialize DataFrames and set "Name" of product column as an index:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["product1", "product2", "product3"],
                    "Price_date1":[1,2,3]}).set_index("Name")


df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["product1", "product2", "product4"],
                    "Price_date2":[3,4,5]}).set_index("Name")
```

Then I concatenate Dataframes, you can pass a list of multiple dataframes here

```
df_con = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Output od df_con:

```
          Price_date1  Price_date2
product1          1.0          3.0
product2          2.0          4.0
product3          3.0          NaN
product4          NaN          5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#### let's assume these are your data

```
data1 = {'Item':['Car','House','Bike'], 'Price':[1.0,2.1,3.0]}
data2 = {'Item':['Car','House','Umbrella'], 'Price':[1.2,2.2,5.2]}
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

#### these are your dataframes

```
data_list = [data1, data2]
```

#### that's the code you wanted:

```
result = pd.DataFrame([])
for i, cr_df in enumerate(data_list):
    data = cr_df.rename(columns={'Price':'Day'+str(i)}).set_index('Item').transpose()
    if i == 0:
        result = data.copy()
    else:
        result = result.append(data)

result = result.transpose()
```

#### that is the output you will obtain:

```
          Day0     Day1
Bike      3.0      nan
Car       1.0      1.2
House     2.1      2.2
Umbrella  nan      5.2
```